# Finding row of Button in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, button, datagrid

I have a program which contains a **DataGrid** with a **DataGridTemplateColumn** populated with buttons. Since the number of rows is variable, all the buttons have their **Command** bound to the same function. However, this means I now need to send a **CommandParameter** to identify the button's "index" (equal to the index of the row it is in). This is what I cannot figure out. What should I send as a **CommandParameter** to know the index of the button?

See below the .xaml (removed everything not related to the problem at hand). The `Button CommandParameter` is what I am trying to fill in.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF.NOptionsTab"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WPF">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CablesColumn">
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CablesClick, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                    Width="50"
                    ToolTip="Set cables pulled in this phase."
                    Content="Set"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid x:Name="PhaseGrid"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Cables" CellTemplate="{StaticResource CablesColumn}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: [MSDN - DataGrid - Selected Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex.aspx) HTH

Comment: Could you use the selected row of the grid either assuming that you have to select the row before you press the button / bring the button out of the grid and only enable when something is selected. 
Then you can bind the selected row to your view model and just use that in the method ?

Comment: You don't need the index or anything like that. Your current code is fine. Using `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` will send the relevant data item (data row) to the Command. The command should operate with the data item rather than indices or other irrelevant information.

Comment: Wow, HighCore. That was it. I admit I hadn't even tried the code as-is because it never occurred to me that was even legal code. But of course. Just copy that into an answer and I'll mark it. Wow.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the index, you could use `IndexOf` on the bound collection, since the current `CommandParameter` is already bound to the data object of the row.

```
var index = BindingCollection.IndexOf(commandParam);
```

You can put this inside your CablesClick `ICommand`'s method.